# python xlwings issue using python3.5

Tags: python-3.5, xlwings

I am using python 3.5 on mac

it has occurred the this error

Why is that?

will I have to try version 3.3 below?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to run the tests? or what are you trying to do?

Comment: I tried the command "python3 runtests.py" but It had error with this capture image

Comment: You can run the tests of your installation by running `nosetests` in the directory of your installation. `runtests.py` is only when you want to run it across python versions.